# PHP - Extract - looping multi-dimensional array with set keys and extracted variables

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, extract

I am extracting data from log files of user data by month. The code itself works, but seems unelegant. I'm looking for ideas about how to neaten it up. Any help is gratefully received.

I have the following code. The data_manip function is called in get_files, which assigns the relevant data from each month into an array called file_resource. The function data_manip is then called which uses 'extract' to define arrays with $names based on the key names that have been defined by month name in the get_files function. I then identify if that variable exists based on the files that have been placed in a data folder (the code for which I have not included). The data_analytic function analyses the data and outputs the results to an html page. At present this solution seems clunky.

What I would like to do is to determine if each month name variable exists (january - december), then if each time that query is verified as true, explode the result of the array $name that corresponds with that specific month name and assign the result to a new array of data, which will be called $january_data, or $february_data etc.

```
function get_files($month_names){ 
                foreach ($month_names as $month_name) { 
                    $file_resource[] = array(
                        $month_name => 
                            file("data/$month_name.log")
                        );
                }
                data_manip($file_resource);
                return $file_resource;
            }

    function data_manip($file_resource){
                foreach ($file_resource as $month_data) {
                    extract($month_data); 
                }
                if (isset($january)){
                    foreach ($january as $january_values) {
                        $january_data[] = explode(' ', $january_values);
                    }
                    echo "<h2>January</h2>";
                    data_analytic($january_data);
                }
                if (isset($february)){
                    foreach ($february as $february_values) {
                        $february_data[] = explode(' ', $february_values);
                    }
                    echo "<h2>February</h2>";
                    data_analytic($february_data);
                }
                if (isset($march)){
                    foreach ($march as $march_values) {
                        $march_data[] = explode(' ', $march_values);
                    }
                    echo "<h2>March</h2>";
                    data_analytic($march_data);
                }
                if (isset($april)){
                    foreach ($april as $april_values) {
                        $april_data[] = explode(' ', $april_values);
                    }
                    echo "<h2>April</h2>";
                    data_analytic($april_data);
                }
                if (isset($may)){
                    foreach ($may as $may_values) {
                        $may_data[] = explode(' ', $may_values);
                    }
                    echo "<h2>May</h2>";
                    data_analytic($may_data);
                }
                if (isset($june)){
                    foreach ($june as $june_values) {
                        $june_data[] = explode(' ', $june_values);
                    }
                    echo "<h2>June</h2>";
                    data_analytic($june_data);
                }
                if (isset($july)){
                    foreach ($july as $july_values) {
                        $july_data[] = explode(' ', $july_values);
                    }
                    echo "<h2>July</h2>";
                    data_analytic($july_data);
                }
                if (isset($august)){
                    foreach ($august as $august_values) {
                        $august_data[] = explode(' ', $august_values);
                    }
                    echo "<h2>August</h2>";
                    data_analytic($august_data);
                }
                if (isset($september)){
                    foreach ($september as $september_values) {
                        $september_data[] = explode(' ', $september_values);
                    }
                    echo "<h2>September</h2>";
                    data_analytic($september_data);
                }
                if (isset($october)){
                    foreach ($october as $october_values) {
                        $october_data[] = explode(' ', $october_values);
                    }
                    echo "<h2>October</h2>";
                    data_analytic($october_data);
                }
                if (isset($november)){
                    foreach ($november as $november_values) {
                        $november_data[] = explode(' ', $november_values);
                    }
                    echo "<h2>November</h2>";
                    data_analytic($november_data);
                }
                if (isset($december)){
                    foreach ($december as $december_values) {
                        $december_data[] = explode(' ', $december_values);
                    }
                    echo "<h2>December</h2>";
                    data_analytic($december_data);
                }
            }
```

Comment: "What I would like to do is to determine if each month name variable exists" => isset function?

Comment: I used isset to determine if that month name file exists, but I was wondering if it's possible to write a function to go through each month (so 12 times), and explode each array each time and assign the result to an array $name that corresponds to that month...